# Mathematica has letters that are already defined with certain attributes that cannot be changed?

Tags: equation-solving

I want to solve a system of equations to find derivatives of sixth order with finite differences. It's easy for me to define g as the function fi and

```
a=fi-6
b=fi-5
.
.
g=fi
h=fi+1
i=fi+2
.
.
.
m=fi+6
```

However, when I use the letters "a" and "h" I have problems, look

I tried with setAttribute[a,Constant] but it does not work. I wonder if mathematica has letters that are already defined with certain attributes that cannot be changed. Thanks

[image]

Comment: 1. The `Constant` attribute applied to `a` only makes all of the derivatives of `a` equal to zero, and nothing else. 2. `a` is black in your screenshot, so you have surely assigned something to it before. Try evaluating your `Solve[]` again in a fresh kernel.

Comment: Is there any chance you might have previously assigned a value to `a` or `h`? This worked for me: `a=.;h=.;Solve[{a==g+(s x)+(((s^2)/2)y),b==g-(s x)+(((s^2)/2)y)},{x,y}]` instantly returns `{{x -> -(-a + b)/(2*s), y -> -((-a - b + 2*g)/s^2)}}`

Comment: @Tiara, it looks like you did not clear the value of `a` after an attempt at a previous method. Additionally, it is not exactly clear what you are trying to do regarding the initial setting of the values of the letters to some function `fi`, you do not define this either. Finally, you do not show an issue with `h` in the image shown, and the code shown should be typed out for ease of those who wish to help you. Can you please rectify some of these? It seems your problem may not simply be solved by  `ClearAll[a]` or `a=.`, but without further clarification this cannot be known with certainty.